# Eigenvalues of $A + I$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I recently noticed an interesting coincidence:

> if matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then $A + I$ has
>   eigenvalues $\lambda_i + 1$

I have tested it on real matrices (I assume that it also holds for imaginary, but have not tried) with various dimensions and up till now this conjecture holds. I know that this is math site, so no one cares about programming, but here is a numpy code if someone is interested:

```
n = 4
A = np.random.randint(-5, 5, (n, n))
print np.linalg.eig(A + np.eye(n))[0] - np.linalg.eig(A)[0]
```

I have tried to prove this conjecture, but with no success. I also searched around but have not found anything similar.

So is this true and if so how can it be proved. Also if there is a more general theorem, I would like to know it as well.

Comment: The result is true in much greater generality. For example, if $p$ is a polynomial, then if $Av=\lambda v$, then $p(A) v = p(\lambda) v$. In your case, $p(x) = 1+x$.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you. If you can post it with a proof, it would be amazing (but I actually think that now after littleO's proof, I know in which direction to go with this proof), otherwise, please post it as another answer as is

Comment: It follows the lines of @littleO's proof. The extension to analytic functions is similar (modulo some details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true.  If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A + c I$, with eigenvalue $\lambda + c$.  Proof:
$$
(A + cI)v = Av + cv = \lambda v + c v = (\lambda + c)v.
$$